# How can declare variables on html page in angular js

Tags: php, angularjs

I want to declare my variable on outside from ng-repeat  and than inside the ng-repeat variable are added and at the bottom of ng-repeat value should be incremented like php loop work.
my html:-

```
{{t_val = 0}}
            <ul id="form-bt-main" class="sec-row" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:31" >
                <li class="form-bt">{{n}}</li>
                <li class="form-bt">{{(t_age + $index + 1)-1}}</li>
                <li class="form-bt" ng-if="$index == 0">{{t_bcv}}</li>
                <li class="form-bt" ng-if="$index != 0">{{t_bcv}}</li>
                <li class="form-bt">{{t_val}}</li>
                {{t_val = t_val +n}}
            </ul>
```

Actually on php my code is like this

```
$begin_contract_value = 0;
for($i= 1; $i <= 30; $i++)
{
$Ending_contract_value = $begin_contract_value - $new_rider_cost - $Annual_withdrawals + $new_est_earnings;
<li><?php echo $begin_contract_value; ?></li>
 $begin_contract_value = $Ending_contract_value ;   

}
```

I want my angular code like php code. but  I have no idea. I want to do it on html page not using app.js. is it possible ?

Comment: So you want to increment `t_val`?

Comment: yes, want my angular functionality should work like php code

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this specific case you can use `$index`:

```
<li class="form-bt">{{$index}}</li>
```

or `ngInit` directive:

```
<ul id="form-bt-main" class="sec-row" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:31" ng-init="t_val = 0">
```

Comment: and than how to increment value in ng-repeat  like 
$begin_contract_value = $Ending_contract_value ;

Answer (score 0):

What I have used in my project to declare a variable (and abviously not displaying it):

```
{{newVariableName = oldVariableName; ""}}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `ng-init` .

```
<ul id="form-bt-main" class="sec-row" ng-init="t_val = 0" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:31" >
            <li class="form-bt">{{n}}</li>
            <li class="form-bt">{{(t_age + $index + 1)-1}}</li>
            <li class="form-bt" ng-if="$index == 0">{{t_bcv}}</li>
            <li class="form-bt" ng-if="$index != 0">{{t_bcv}}</li>
            <li class="form-bt">{{t_val}}</li>
            {{t_val = t_val +n}}
        </ul>
```

for more details go to this link :  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit